# Next.js API function works when using "vercel dev" or running and building locally but it does not work on Vercel

Tags: node.js, next.js, stripe-payments, next.js14, clerk

I am having problems with **Clerk** **webhooks** that create, delete or update a **Stripe** customer. (the name of the file is `route.ts`, the path for my api endpoint is `/api/clerk/webhook`) working on **Vercel** properly, I've checked the **api secrets** they are **correct**. I have **tested** this by running `vercel dev` and then using **ngrok** to make a tcp proxy and test trough **Clerk** dashboard and it worked. I am not sure how to fix it whatsoever. But I keep getting error `405` or error `500` on **Vercel** with no response, I have checked **Vercel** **logs** and I see these **errors**:

```
    тип Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js'
Require stack:
- /var/task/.next/server/app/api/clerk/webhook/route.js
- /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js
- /var/task/___next_launcher.cjs
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:11:25613
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at r.<computed>.e._load (/var/task/___vc/__launcher/bridge-server-72TT5FOD.js:1:1574)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at b.require (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:11:25829)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at 30517 (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/clerk/webhook/route.js:1:1304)
    at _0x4476b9 (/var/task/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:1707)
    at 50837 (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/940.js:1:21459) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/var/task/.next/server/app/api/clerk/webhook/route.js',
    '/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js',
    '/var/task/___next_launcher.cjs'
  ],
  page: '/api/clerk/webhook'
}
```

Code of `/app/api/clerk/webhook/route.ts`:

```
// /app/api/clerk/webhook/route.ts
// Imports
import { Webhook } from 'svix'
import { headers } from 'next/headers'
import { WebhookEvent } from '@clerk/nextjs/server'
import { clerkClient } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import initStripe from "stripe";

// Initilize Stripe.js
const stripe = new initStripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!, {
  typescript: true,
  apiVersion: "2023-10-16",
});

/**
 * Either create or update (sync with clerk data) stripe customer according to data in Clerk.
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} userId - The id of the user.
 */
async function manageStripeCustomer(userId: string): Promise<void> {
  const userClerk = await clerkClient.users.getUser(userId);
  if (!userClerk) {
    throw new Error(`User with the ID specified was not found.`);
  }

  const stripeId = userClerk.privateMetadata?.stripeId;

  const primaryEmailAddressId = userClerk.primaryEmailAddressId;
  if (!primaryEmailAddressId) {
    throw new Error('Primary email address ID not found.');
  }

  const primaryEmailObject = userClerk.emailAddresses.find(emailObj => emailObj.id === primaryEmailAddressId);
  if (!primaryEmailObject) {
    throw new Error('Primary email address object not found.');
  }

  const primaryEmail = primaryEmailObject.emailAddress;
  if (!primaryEmail) {
    throw new Error('Customer does not have an email. ');
  }

  const customerName = [userClerk.username, userClerk.firstName, userClerk.lastName].filter(Boolean).join(' ');
  if (!customerName) {
    throw new Error('Customer does not have a name. ');
  }

  let Update = false;
  if (stripeId) {
    const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(stripeId.toString());
    if (customer && !customer.deleted && customer.id) {
      Update = true;
    }
  }

  const customerData = {
    email: primaryEmail,
    name: customerName,
    preferred_locales: ['sk', 'cs', 'en'],
    metadata: {
      clerkId: userClerk.id,
    },
  };

  if (Update) {
    // User is already linked with a Stripe customer, updating the customer.
    await stripe.customers.update(stripeId as string, customerData);
  } else {
    // User is not linked with a Stripe customer, creating a new customer.
    const stripeCustomer = await stripe.customers.create(customerData);

    await clerkClient.users.updateUserMetadata(userId, {
      privateMetadata: {
        stripeId: stripeCustomer.id,
        isSubscribed: false,
        isAdmin: false,
      },
    });
  }
}


/**
 * Delete user based on the Clerk user id.
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} userId - The id of the user.
 */
async function deleteUser(userId: string)
{
  // List all customers
  const customers = await stripe.customers.list();
  // Filter customers with the matching clerkId in metadata
  await customers.data.filter(customer => {
    // Check if clerkId is equal to the user id.
    if (customer?.metadata?.clerkId === userId)
    {
      // Delete matching customer
      stripe.customers.del(customer.id);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Handle POST requests.
 * @constructor
 * @param {Request} req - Request
 */
export async function POST(req: Request) {
 
  try {
  // Clerk Dashboard -> Webhooks -> choose the webhook
  const WEBHOOK_SECRET = process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET
 
  if (!WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
    throw new Error('Please add WEBHOOK_SECRET from Clerk Dashboard to .env or .env.local')
  }
 
  // Get the headers
  const headerPayload = headers();
  const svix_id = headerPayload.get("svix-id");
  const svix_timestamp = headerPayload.get("svix-timestamp");
  const svix_signature = headerPayload.get("svix-signature");
 
  // If there are no headers, error out
  if (!svix_id || !svix_timestamp || !svix_signature) {
    throw new Error('Error occured -- no svix headers');
  }
 
  // Get the body
  const payload = await req.json()
  const body = JSON.stringify(payload);
 
  // Create a new Svix instance with your secret.
  const wh = new Webhook(WEBHOOK_SECRET);
 
  let evt: WebhookEvent
 
  // Verify the payload with the headers
    evt = wh.verify(body, {
      "svix-id": svix_id,
      "svix-timestamp": svix_timestamp,
      "svix-signature": svix_signature,
    }) as WebhookEvent
 
  // Get the ID and type
  const { id } = evt.data;
  const eventType = evt.type;
 

  if (id)
  {
  switch (eventType) {
    // If user is updated or created
    case 'user.updated':
    case 'user.created':
      await manageStripeCustomer(id);
      break;
    // Action for deleted user
    case 'user.deleted':
      await deleteUser(id);
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error('Event not handeled. ');
      return;
  }
  }
  else
  {
    throw new Error('No id provided. ');
  }

  return new Response('', { status: 200 })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error verifying webhook:', err);
    return new Response('Error occured: ' + err?.toString(), {
      status: 400,
    })
  }
}
```

**Thank you very much!** Any **help** is **highly** **appriciated**!